# What is the best way to work with environments in AWS API Gateway?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I am using AWS to build an API, and deploy this to multiple stages.

When a call is made to a specific *environment*, I need to get a *stage variable* in **Lambda** and then data is recorded in a **DynamoDB** table such as *"environment-Table"*.

Is this the best way to work with environments (like development, production etc) using AWS API Gateway, Lambda and DynamoDB?

Answer (score 0):

It difficult to say what the best approach is for your specific situation, given the limited data in your post.  Managing multiple environments such as development and production was one of the intended uses of stage and stage variables.  I don't see any obvious problems with what your are proposing.

Depending on your use case, you can call a Lambda function to record data in DynamoDB, or you may be able to skip the Lambda function and record the data in DynamoDB directly using the AWS proxy integration type.